# We should be able to vote for our posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting

Just now, I made an excellent answer and I feel more than entitled to vote for it.

Could we please allow users to vote for their own posts?

Comment: "I feel more than entitled" is a curious phrase. What is *more than* entitled? Obligated?

Comment: Would you ever **downvote** your own answer?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you knew that it was wrong but couldn't delete it because it was accepted, possibly.  Certainly not often.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you posted an answer says you think it is Wonderful?  In the end, it is for the community to judge.

Comment: @BilltheLizard People do say things like "you're more than welcome to..." If I'm "welcome to" then "I'm allowed to..." and presumably the people saying it find it desirable that I do whatever I'm allowed to do. But "*more* than welcome"? Are they going to *pay* me? Force me? Hold it against me if I don't do it?

Comment: @Louis "Welcome to..." implies you are graciously given permission. If you're "more than welcome to...", it is implied that you should take the specified privilege for granted without needing to ask. My interpretation, of course.

Comment: @Louis "More than welcome" means you're *encouraged* to do whatever you're asking to do. There are plenty of levels beyond "welcome." You gave a few examples. I don't know what's beyond "entitled."

Comment: @BilltheLizard Beyond entitled? Brats, as far as the eye can see.

Comment: @BilltheLizard One could be not only entitled to do something but morally obligated to do so.

Comment: @Louis Which brings us back to my original comment. It is not the case that we are morally obligated to upvote our own posts, so it makes no sense to describe oneself as "beyond entitled" to do so.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That you do not accept what that interpretation entails does not preclude that this may be precisely what the phrase "more than entitled" *can* mean.

Comment: Use socks!!! :D

Comment: @Louis I didn't ask what it *can* mean.

Comment: I tried to look at your "excellent" answer and found you didn't answer anything today. Looking at your past answers, there's definite room for improvement - 4 out of your last 5 answers consist only of a code dump without any explanation, that's hardly excellent.

Comment: This won't benefit anyone at all. Every user from spammers to trolls will start upvoting their answers

Comment: Maybe he was feeling like downvoting it, and didn't want to have to get penalized. Perhaps we could have penalty free down votes on our own posts!

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry for reviving an old thread, but I know I would (though only on per-site metas)

Answer (score 52):

Um. No.

What's the point?

Everyone would vote for their own posts.

Comment: But the free rep??

Comment: @bluefeet That's true. We should allow people to upvote their own posts and get the exact same kind of free rep they get when they accept a self-answer.

Comment: @Louis to complement this beautiful picture, we also should allow to get +2 rep for edits to own posts, and, _of course_, allow to award our bounties to our own answers

Comment: @Louis I think we should get **ten times** how much rep we get from self-accepted answers!

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think in this case we can be extremely generous so something like eleventy million times would seem appropriate.

Comment: But my internet swag needs boosting D:

Answer (score 18):

If the answer is truly so "excellent" people will vote for it for you. This is way too open for abuse, and basically entitles people to free rep for no reason.

You may think your answer is awesome, but for all you know, it could be completely wrong. This is the community benefit.

PS. According to your most recent answers -- they are not awesome answers. They are code dumps that if I found outside of the meta-effect, I would downvote for no explanations.