# Why can you vote for your own topic request?

Tags: discussion, documentation, voting, upvotes, documentation-topics

We all know that you can't vote for your own posts, and there's a [good reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276208/we-should-be-able-to-vote-for-our-posts) for that.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I created 2 topic proposals, and both of them were upvoted by myself. Furthermore, the system automatically upvotes your topic proposals after creating them.

I don't see why we should be able to vote for our own topic proposals, but not our own questions and answers. Besides, everyone would vote for their own posts, right?

Why can you vote for your own topic requests on Stack Overflow Documentation?

Comment: I noticed that, too. It doesn't make much sense, might be an oversight.

Comment: I'm most upset that I cannot downvote my own topic requests. I have some horrible ideas.

Comment: If a topic request has _n_ votes, _n_ people have requested it.  It's entirely logical that the original requester counts.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom This makes sense, as the system automatically upvotes your topic request after you create it. But why would anyone want to un-upvote their own topic request? If someone doesn't want to request for it anymore, they can just remove it.

Comment: @narawagames Perhaps they no longer want it, but others still do.  In that case, it would make more sense to let you remove your vote than to make you remove the request and get someone else to remake it.